# Can't access to power bi api from ROPC

Tags: azure-active-directory, powerbi, microsoft-graph-api, azure-web-app-service

I try to get reports from power bi api. There is app with permissions, [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMRnm.png). My request [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRXmc.png). If i insert "openid" to scopes or any of Microsoft Graph scopes, request return access token. This token dont let me access to reports. If i insert "Report.Read.All" or any of Power BI scopes, i recieve invalid_grant error: 'The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID  named 'Интеграция с Битрикс24'. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.'. Request from error message was send was sent by me many times. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bu6eU.png). Please tell me what could be the mistake. What setting could I forget?

Answer (score 1):

need to insert full url scope in request body to access power bi token. https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/Report.Read.All instead of Report.Read.All

Answer (score 0):

I could help you with an alternative where you can update the Graph Client to a Newer version. The admin of the subscription can grant the consent through the portal as shown below from Home > App > API Permissions.
We have done the following steps:
Using the following Steps:

1. Revoke all admin consent.
2. Remove all permissions
3. Add removed permissions back.
4. Grant admin consent.

Here is the Microsoft Document which you can refer to : [Construct the URL for granting tenant-wide admin consent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/grant-admin-consent#construct-the-url-for-granting-tenant-wide-admin-consent)